# VB.NET- how to limit checkbox selection in listview?

Tags: vb.net, listview, checkbox

I want to limit the checkbox selection in listview into 2
help please.

```
If lvbooklist.CheckedItems.Count >= 2 Then
     e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked
     MsgBox("Only 2 Book can be borrow per day")
Else

End If
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This question appears to be lacking.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be in the `ItemCheck` Event, and you should only be preventing a CheckBox going from an Unchecked state to a Checked state (otherwise they'll also get a message when you uncheck an item when you have two selected already):

```
Private Sub lvbooklist_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles lvbooklist.ItemCheck
    If lvbooklist.CheckedItems.Count = 2 AndAlso e.CurrentValue = CheckState.Unchecked Then
        e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked
        MessageBox.Show("Only 2 Books can be borrowed per day.")
    End If
End Sub
```